# How do I make my drop-down menu responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Can somebody please help me with my nav and drop-down menu?
They work fine with websites, but not on mobile devices.
Here is my HTML code:

```js
@media only screen and(max - width: 700 px) {
  .navbar - nav {
    width: 100 % ;
    background: #F8F9FA;
    position: absolute;
    z - index: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="navbarfixed">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html" target="_blank">About<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://github.com/MaariaCaroline" target="_blank">Github</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="blog.html" target="_blank">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a href="language.html" target="_blank"><button class="dropbtn">Language resources
              <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button></a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="english.resources.html" target="_blank">English</a>
            </br>
            <a href="german.resources.html" target="_blank">German</a>
            </br>
            <a href="korean.resources.html" target="_blank">Korean</a>
            <br>
            <a href="japanese.resources.html" target="_blank">Japanese</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <li class="nav-item">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I tried using `@media only screen`. Could someone please tell me what do I do wrong?

Comment: It would be nice to see your CSS styles for the classes used in HTML. A snippet would be even nicer :)

Comment: #navbarSupportedContent {
  padding-left: 3%;
}
#navbarfixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
padding-bottom: 2%;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 70%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropbtn {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 4%;
  margin-left: 0%;
  background-color: #F8F9FA;
} 
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

Comment: and here:     .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 6% 7%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: darksalmon;
  opacity: 0.40;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
} I don't know why it is displayed in such a strange way. I apologize.

Comment: Are these your custom styles you are using a CSS library?

Comment: I believe these are from W3Schools.com, I just adjusted them a little bit. :)

Comment: Sorry, but with the styles you provided the menu doesn't look complete. Can you make a snippet so that we see the full version of your menu? Then it will be easier to help

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="index.html" class="active">About</a>
  <a href="https://github.com/MaariaCaroline">Github</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="blog.html" target="_blank">Blog</a>
  <a href="language.html" target="_blank">Language resources</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">LANGUAGES
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="english.resources.html">English</a>
      <a href="german.resources.html">German</a>
      <a href="korean.resources.html">Korean</a>
      <a href="japanese.resources.html">Japanese</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#XXX">YOUR TEXT</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>NAAVBAR</h2>
  <p>RESPONSIVE.</p>
  <p>Dropdown.</p>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it seems like I cannot make it work. I also tried W3Schools and their tutorial, but for some reason, I just cannot make the nav responsive. But thank you :).

Comment: You welcome Maria try to send the head of your the html file, or the index file to see if is another mistake in other part.